# Can I use spells with dual mana symbols against Iona, Shield of Emeria?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I use spells with dual mana symbols against [Iona, Shield of Emeria](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIona%2c%20Shield%20of%20Emeria%5d)?

For example, if my opponent names white, can I still cast [Unmake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnmake%5d)?

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast Unmake.

---

Those are called hybrid mana symbols.

> 105.2. [...] An object is the color or colors of the mana symbols in its mana cost, regardless of the color of its frame. An object’s color or colors may also be defined by a color indicator or a characteristic-defining ability. See rule 202.2.
>
> 107.4e [...] A hybrid mana symbol is all of its component colors.

So Unmake is white and black, so Unmake is white, so you can't it.

Comment: Well damn. Looks like I can't throw a few in my mono white sideboard to deal with that. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Devoid cards would work, but there's only one devoid white spell and it isn't useful for removal. I recommend an [artifact](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262674)

Comment: @Yvain All Is Dust works as colorless removal. So does Spine of Ish Sah and a few others. They all have the same problem : they're expensive.